# Problem with consecutive day visit count

Tags: support, badges

A while back I got to 98 days consecutive visits then next day I visit the site to see that the day before I had missed. I was back to day 1 again and was very upset that I got so close to the 100 day mark.

I religiously visit this site everyday whether its from my work computer, home computer, laptop, smart phone or tablet. I'm so devoted to WPSE I even have my home page set to WPSE so not to miss a day. When the first day I missed I thought that cannot be right as I could clearly remember visiting the website. I had a few words to say in chat about it as I'm sure Rarst can remember.

Back then I just dusted it off and said I'll try again but for the same thing to happen for the third time there is no way I'm going to hit that magical number of 100 when something isn't right.

Apparently yesterday I didn't visit WPSE site at all when clearly I did. I distinctly remember getting to my computer at 8:30AM opening my web browser, WPSE home page loaded with me logged in and then clicking the join Stop Press chat room. All day I was sat in the chat room and occasionally clicking some of the question feeds from the chat room to see if I could add my two cents.

I login with my Google account to SE and for an extra safe measure I have my Yahoo and Facebook account linked as login too.

Is there something wrong with the tracking of daily visits or am I just blacking out for a day and imagining what happened when I blacked out?

Answer (score 3):

The system seems to "miss" days sometimes. I've run into this a lot too, on a number of the sites, where I get dropped back to 1 consecutive day even though I've certainly visited on the missing day. I tend to visit two (or even three) times a day, typically morning and afternoon, and yet I sometimes lose days. Very weird, but it's been going on a long time.

Comment: Usually, visiting multiple times a day is less susceptible to this issue. The main thing that causes a lot of people issue is that they visit on their own day, which doesn't necessarily match the UTC day. By visiting once in the morning and once in the evening each day, it largely overcomes that hurdle. It is bad if there are still days being missed in that kind of approach.

Answer (score 2):

Only visits to interior pages count, not the "outside" pages, and our day is from 00:00:00 UTC to 23:59:59 UTC.

Sounds like the first part is what got you here.

Comment: Please define interior pages? I did home page visit 8:30AM GMT then throughout the working day a number of visits to question pages.

Comment: in that case it was probably the 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 UTC that tripped you up..

Comment: Kindly explain how, because I cannot see it. I'm in the UK which is one hour difference to the server. I visited the website many times during the day and the day before that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems with providing joke badges (or with gamification itself) - the game mechanic starts to become more important than the game.

Personally, I think the 100 days badge should either be deleted or made bronze.

Comment: I agree with that :)

Comment: @anu it doesn't matter if the badge is there or not. The fact of the matter is that the consecutive day count is not working as it should. The badge is merely there to indicate to others your efforts. I'm not here to understand the `mechanics`, I'm here because the site said I wasn't on when I clearly was.

Comment: @brady - you're upset because you didn't get the badge. that's the only reason the consecutive day count matters. Let's put it another way, how does it matter that the consecutive day count is - in your opinion - broken?

Comment: @anu - I'm upset that the consecutive count on my profile shows 3 days when actually I've been visiting this site everyday since I signed up. Therefore that metric is lying and displaying incorrectly. Badge or no badge the consecutive count is not right.